# Steam "Turn On Accessibility" Problems

Tags: steam

I have SO many problems with Steam, this one has been happening for a while. Every time I launch a game, a notification pops up saying "The in-game overlays require accessibility to be enabled, enable it now from your settings" So, I go onto my iMac settings, and it's already turned on. So I check Steam preferences, it's turned on. And that is when I get confused. I have tried turning it off, restarting my computer, re-installing Steam. And much more. It's been going on for so long now, and it means I can't open alt+tab menu and it also means I can't download mods and it means many more things, so...

Comment: Do you need the in-game overlay? You could always disable it if you never use it.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Yeah, No. I NEED the overlay. ;-;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running on a MAC Operating System I have found an article that has been published on the Apple website discussion page concerning your question:

> - Quit Steam and create a backup or two with Time Machine.
> - Open Finder and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and enter `~/Library/Preferences`
> - Find the file `com.apple.systempreferences.plist` and move it (not copy) to your desktop.
> - Restart your PC and test Steam.
>
> If it's working delete the `.plist` file from your desktop. If not, return it to the `~/Library/Preferences` folder (overwriting the new copy). Note though that this will likely destroy some system preferences; because of this it may be safer to use a plist editor.
> [Source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7912291?start=0&tstart=0)

This client is running a MAC Operating System as well, and seems to have the same issue. If you read the top comment / answer by **Eric Root**, it explains the instructions for this problem that is occurring in regards to the Steam overlay.

Comment: Could you give a quick breakdown of the answer here, as per site rules.